# Date and Time Picker not displaying in firefox?

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struct

I am using struts 2 for front end developing. My problem is js datepicker is not displayed in firefox only and except one page it's coming in all pages. In chrome working good. Why its' not coming. Please let me know if anyone knows.

Comment: You could help by posting more info. Do the javascript console trows any errors? Can you post relevant code?

Comment: are you using jQuery datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools, in Firefox the datepicker doesn't show up in a html input field.